# How to hide the mplay32 window in CMD?

Tags: winapi, cmd, windows-xp

When I execute the at command:

```
at  10:10   mplay32.exe  /play c:\m1.mp3
```

No media play window is displayed on my screen, but I can hear the music playing.

When I execute the command in XP:

```
mplay32.exe  /play c:\m1.mp3
```

I can hear the music playing but there is a media play window displayed on my screen, how can I hide this window? How to let media play not to be displayed on my screen?

How can I do it in cmd not in the form of `at sometime`?

[image: cmd]

Comment: I've removed the second question - see why at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts. Just ask the second question as a second post.

Comment: Project + Add Reference, COM tab, tick "Windows Media Player".  MSDN page [is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562692%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @HansPassant That's for Windows Media Player, not Microsoft Media Player.

Comment: I think there is no simple way. Will you accept/reward an answer involving a tiny C source code? (you would have to compile it)

Comment: Of course, little point in using an ancient discontinued player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to accomplish this using only the default tools of Windows.

You can either switch to a player that supports some sort of silent mode (regarding the GUI, not the sound) or **compile [this snippet](https://gist.github.com/maxtruxa/7883151)** I just wrote for you.

To play your music you would then simply do:

```
hstart mplay32.exe /play c:\m1.mp3
```

Answer (score 0):

`wv_player` is a command line (and gui) media player that can play an audio file with no interface.

http://www.webxpace.net/

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to start the player minimized:

```
start /min mplay32.exe /play c:\m1.mp3
```

It's not actually hidden - an icon will appear in the taskbar - but it won't interfere with your workflow if you launch it asynchronously.

If you want the player to be completely hidden it needs to be launched with the `ShowWindow` flag in `STARTUPINFO` set to `SW_HIDE`.  I'm not aware of an existing command-line utility that does this but you could write one yourself very easily.

Or you could use a different application as suggested by the other respondent.